# AWS api-gateway mapping template for multiValueQueryStringParameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I neet AWS API-gateway mapping template that when I call **https://somelinke/article?foo=1&foo=2&foo=3&bar=4** generate below data for lambda function:

```
{
    "resource": "/article",
    "path": "/article",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "queryStringParameters": {
        foo:"3",
        bar:"4"
    },
    "multiValueQueryStringParameters": {
        foo:["1,", "2", "3"]
        bar:["4"]
    },,
    "body": null,
    "isBase64Encoded": false
  }
```

When I choose **"Use Lambda Proxy integration"** it generates expected values, but for some reason, I cannot use **"Lambda Proxy integration"**. I want to write a mapping template manually, But I just receive the last value of each key and other values assigned to the key are not accessible.

```
{
            foo:"3",
            bar:"4"
}
```

Comment: If you want to add additional fields, then why you didn't prefer to use stage variables. It will come default event provided by api-gateway.

Comment: I just edit my previous question and do some simplification.

Comment: I also have this same question.

Comment: I think this is because you are using version 1 of the payload format (selected when specifying the integration). I have not used that format but my general understanding is that the proxy may be required to do what you want in that version. In version 2 that changed and the `queryStringParameters` entry is a comma separated list. Why these decisions .... Unclear to me.